# How to efficiently find "duplicate" posts, where the titles are different, using metadata to match posts?

Tags: wp-query, duplicates, comparison

The website I'm working on collects information on film reels. A `'film'` is a custom post type. Each 'film' is one post.

The user bulk uploads films from different sources. Because of this, some films get uploaded twice, from different sources.

I'd like to find each film that is uploaded twice and merge the information contained in the two films into one.

The problem is that the information of each film is not always entered the same. Sometimes the title is different in spelling, or just plain listed differently, or the listing for a metadata field like 'production_company' is spelled differently, for instance.

I've written code that takes one film, and goes through the entire database, looking for similar entries. My code works fine. The problem is that it is INCREDIBLY slow. I have to refresh the page several times to even make it through checking one film against each other film in the database (of 200k films).

I'm wondering if there is a way to rewrite or rethink this problem so I can write a more efficient system. I'm considering hooking into `wp_cron` and running this every 5 minutes for all of eternity, but that doesn't seem like a great longterm efficient solution.

Here's my code - I use a taxonomy called 'notaduplicate' to filter through the results, so the loop doesn't show the same results each time. I set the post ID of each film that is not a duplicate to the terms of a film.

How can I make this a more efficient code that can go through more data at once?

```
<?php
$film_a_args = array(
  'numberposts' => 1,
  'post_type'   => 'film'
);
$all_films = get_posts( $film_a_args );        //this gets the first film, I'd like to be able to run more than one at a time, but this function is so expensive i can only do 1
foreach($all_films as $single_film){
    $film_a_post_id=$single_film->ID;
    $title=get_the_title($film_a_post_id);
    $film_b_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'film',
        'posts_per_page'=> 1000,
        'tax_query'=> array(
          array(
            'taxonomy'=>'notaduplicate',  //notaduplicate says that this film has been checked against another film, and it is not a duplicate
            'field'=>'slug',
            'terms'=>$film_a_post_id,
            'operator'=>'NOT IN',
          ),
        ),
    );
    // The Query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $film_b_args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
      $i=0;
      while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
          $the_query->the_post();
          $film_b_post_id=get_the_ID();
          $film_a_permalink=get_the_permalink($film_a_post_id);
          $film_b_permalink=get_the_permalink($film_b_post_id);
          if($film_a_post_id==$film_b_post_id){
              wp_set_post_terms( $film_a_post_id, $film_a_post_id, 'notaduplicate',  true); //if the film sees itself
              echo 'film set terms not a duplicate with itself';
          }else{
              $metafields=array('film_title','series','duration_in_minutes','production_company','format','color','sound','online_copy_link','wikipedia_link','imdb_link');
              foreach($metafields as $metafield){
                  $film_a_metafield=get_post_meta(  $film_a_post_id,  $key = $metafield, $single = true );
                  $film_b_metafield=get_post_meta(  $film_b_post_id,  $key = $metafield, $single = true );
                  if($film_a_metafield){
                      if($film_a_metafield == $film_b_metafield){
                          //if the two films have the same metafield
                          //and the meta field is an 'auspicious' one, add 5 to $i
                          if($metafield=='film_title'||$metafield=='duration_in_minutes'||$metafield=='online_copy_link'||$metafield=='wikipedia_link'||$metafield=='imdb_link'){
                              $i=$i+5;
                          }else $i++; //else add 1 to $i
                      }
                  }
              }
              if($i<5){     //if $i meets the 'duplicate threshold'
                  $i=0;
                  //update taxonomy 'not a duplicate with post id for both films' 
                  //this sets a term (of the other films id) for each film, so they will cycle through search.
                  wp_set_post_terms( $film_a_post_id, $film_b_post_id, 'notaduplicate',  true); 
                  wp_set_post_terms( $film_b_post_id, $film_a_post_id, 'notaduplicate',  true);
                  echo '<li>' ,'Film B: ','<a href='.$film_b_permalink.'>'. get_the_title() .'</a>',' Post Id: '.$film_b_post_id.'Has been checked against: ', '</li>';
                  echo '<li>' ,'Film A (Original Film): ','<a href='.$film_a_permalink.'>'. get_the_title($film_a_post_id) .'</a>',' Post Id: '.$film_a_post_id. '</li>';
                  echo 'and taxonomy has been updated';
                  echo '<hr>';
              }else{
                //here i will write the code to merge the films together into one post
                //for now i just have a little ranking system
                  echo '<h3>'.get_the_title($film_b_post_id).' has '.$i.' duplicate points.','</h3>';
                  echo '<ul>';
                  echo '<li>' ,'Film A (Original Film): ','<a href='.$film_a_permalink.'>'. get_the_title($film_a_post_id) .'</a>',' Post Id: '.$film_a_post_id. '</li>';
                  echo '<li>' ,'Film B (Possible Duplicate): ','<a href='.$film_b_permalink.'>'. get_the_title() .'</a>',' Post Id: '.$film_b_post_id. '</li>';
                  if($i>=7){
                      echo 'This is most likely a duplicate';
                  }else{
                      echo 'This is probably a duplicate';
                  }
                  echo 'End Of Possible Duplicate: ','<a href='.$film_b_permalink.'>'. get_the_title() .'</a>','<hr>';
                  $i=0;
                  echo '</ul>';
              }   
          }
      }
    } else {
    // no posts found
    }
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: It would probably be *some* more efficient to query for similar posts either when the user enters a title in the Editor, or else when they try to publish a post. It might make sense to add either a metabox (if it's Classic Editor) or an Inspector Panel (if it's Block Editor) that searches for similar entries in the background while the user is editing.

Comment: Great question, I often deal with trying to find content that is too similar and will hurt my SEO, so I'll be very interested in following this to (hopefully) a resolution. I wonder if - going forward - you might add a custom field to hold something like IMDb's ID number, require it during upload, and then you can (fairly) easily search for duplicates on that field? Or possibly prevent an upload if a film with the same IMDb ID is already in the database?

Comment: A metabox is a great idea for a user who uploads one at a time. Want to write up the shell of a metabox and copy some code in for an accepted answer? The user of this site bulk uploads (1000s at a time), so that solution wouldn't work for this rare case.

Comment: A unique ID (like matching results against the IMDB database)is a great idea. This would give a non-variable to match against. I wonder if IMDB has the kind of info this user wants/needs. Great idea!